# Unable to use `library ("ff")` in R 3.4.2

Tags: r, ff

I am not able to use `library ("ff")`. I don't know which library package `ff` comes under. I am using R 3.4.2.

Comment: Have you done a `install.packages("ff")` before trying to load?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use quotes in the library-command. also make sure the package you're trying to load is actually installed. try this code:

```
if ("ff" %in% rownames(installed.packages()) == FALSE) {
  install.packages("ff")
}

library(ff)
```

or use the pacman-package:

```
if (!require("pacman"))
  install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(ff)
```